# Start /b command is not completing the command and exit SSH straightaway

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, cmd

I am using ssh to run a bat file which will be running multiple commands in parallel as below:

```
(
start "" cmd /c "cd "C:/Users/desktop" && python -m command"
start "" cmd /c "cd "C:/Users/desktop" && python -m command"
) | pause >nul
```

the bat file is able to run however, i requrie the output of the python to be shown in the command window. I have tried to include /b in the command

```
(
start /b "" cmd /c "cd "C:/Users/desktop" && python -m command"
start /b "" cmd /c "cd "C:/Users/desktop" && python -m command"
) | pause >nul
```

However, the above does not work. It exited before finishing the run of the python commands.

Comment: Any reason why you can't run it like this? `start "" /D "C:\Users\desktop" python -m command`

Comment: Hi @Squashman , I have tried this but it works the same as the one I have currently. I need the output of the python to be display in the first command prompt which is why start /b seems to be the answer as I need the output to tell SSH that its still running the commands, so the SSH does not close while executing the bat file

Comment: Have you tried Squashman's suggestion with the `/B` option added also?

Comment: Hi @aschipfl yeap i did. Doesnt work as well, it exited before the python scripts are done running.